# Java check if domain exists without using outside WhoIs server

Tags: java, domain-name, whois

so I need to check a large amount of domains for availability in my program. I tried to use outside WhoIs servers, but they usually rate limit me. Does anyone know of a way to check if the domains are available on the host machine? I thought about doing a DNS lookup but someone could have registered the domain and just put a random DNS that resolves to nothing. Thanks!

Comment: Try accessing the domain itself, if it already exists, that will eliminate around 30%+.  Also look into paying those 'rate limited' services.  That will generally unlock their access sizes.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I need it to be 100 percent accurate and I would rather keep it at no cost :/

Comment: I think you are out of luck then.

Comment: If the Domain sevice provider has those interfaces and you are authorized to use then, that might be doable. Or it has to be a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a free whois library that may help. The library contains a large list of whois servers. So you could use this and spread the queries between each of the whois servers that work for that top level domain. If that doesn't work then you would have to fall back to doing a dns lookup on the address.

Comment: Any links to the library? Advises on how to use it?

Comment: Doh! That was a bit stupid of me. Here is the link  https://code.google.com/p/jfreewhois/

Comment: To get a list of servers for a hostname call ServerDefinitionFinder.getServerDefinitionsForHostName("stackoverflow.com"). Then pass one of those WhoisServerDefinitions into the call to Whois.getRawWhoisResults( "stackoverflow.com", whoisServerDefinition ).

Comment: There is only one relevant authoritative whois server per TLD so there is no way to share the load among more than one. Also using DNS to check if a domain exists or not is not a good idea since a domain can be registered but not delegated in the DNS.